# Binding repeater values outside dropdown

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, repeater

```
 Sub ddlID_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Try
        Dim strConnection As String = "Data Source=Name\MSSQLSERVER12;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=true"
        Dim cmdText As String = "SELECT [id], [name], [address],[email] FROM [tbl_StudentRecord] where id=@id"

        Dim data As New DataTable()
        Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(cmdText, strConnection)
        adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", ddlID.SelectedValue)
        adapter.Fill(data)
        rptbind.DataSource = data
        rptbind.DataBind()

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

In this "data" will come but not bound into repeater ...?
How can I display data into repeater?

```
 <table style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlID" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" AppendDataBoundItems="True" DataTextField="ID" DataValueField="ID"
                OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlID_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <asp:ListItem Text="--Select--" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </table>

        <asp:Repeater ID="rptbind" runat="server">
        </asp:Repeater>
```

In this "data" will come but not bound into repeater ...?
How can I display data into repeater?

Comment: which field you want to show in repeater?

Comment: [id], [name], [address],[email] field

Answer (score 0):

Shown below is example to bind data to Repeater (design Mode):

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptReferences" runat="server">
  <ItemTemplate>                    
    <asp:Label ID="lblRef" ForeColor="#0869BD" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FieldName")%>' visible="true"></asp:Label>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: can i do this using jquery

Comment: @sambasiva : thanks and yes you can..refer http://nitindhiman.blogspot.in/2014/12/bind-repeater-using-jqueryajax_22.html